# Do NEC receptacle spacing rules apply to solid (half-wall) banisters

Tags: electrical, receptacle, nec

I have a solid banister over my stairs. If it counts as a wall per NEC, then it needs an outlet. I can't find the reference in NEC defining a wall. Anybody know if this counts?

[image]

Comment: It is nice to have more outlets than the code requires.  In your case, where would you plug in a vacuum cleaner to vacuum these floors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would consider this a hallway and hallways less than 10' do not require an outlet NEC 210.52.H. This is not a room as defined by 210.52.A.

The commentary for 210.52.a.3 says:

> any wall space that is unbroken along the floor line by doors, fireplaces, archways and similar openings must be included in the measurement. Room dividers such as bar type counters and railings are required to be in the 6' measurement.

But this would be a hallway or landing. Local code may require an outlet at the landings but since it is not defined in NEC 210.52 there is no requirement for them in landings.

Comment: As Ed points out this appears to be a hallway. Hallways are not included in the 2 foot wall rule of 210.52(A). The rules for hallways would be found in 210.52(H).

Comment: I've attempted to quote the part that appeared to be a quote from the NEC. If I've missed, please feel free to correct.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a railing and would fall in the 6' measurement.

Comment: You're implying that it _does_ need an outlet? What if this were an open railing with spindles instead of drywalled? Would it still need an outlet?